# Vuetify / v-text-field / mask : bad cursor position

Tags: vuetify.js

**Problem**
When applying a mask on an input, the value changes but the cursor is not at the end of the input.

**Example**
When typing : 0123456789 I get +33 2 34 56 71 30

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pflaho/21nrm6tp/5/

**Code**

```
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js'></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Phone</h2>
  <v-text-field type="text" v-model="tel" :mask="mask"></v-text-field>
</div>
```

And

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    mask: "",
    tel: ""
  },
  watch: {
    tel(v) {
      if (v.charAt(0) == "0") {
        this.tel = '+33'
        this.mask = "+33 # ## ## ## ##"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Not sure you can use `33` in mask... Refer to docs, it might be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `mask` every time `tel` change. You've to set it only **once** (only if it's emtpy and you need it based on your condition).

And reset it when not needed.

```
tel(v) {
    if (v.charAt(0) == "0") {
        this.tel = '+33'
        if(!this.mask.length){ this.mask = "+33 # ## ## ## ##" }
    }
    else{
        this.mask = ""
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8syr179/1/)

Comment: I tried your solution but I changed if(!mask.length) to if(!this.mask.length) and I remove the else statement but I have the same problem

Comment: If you remove the else statement it won't work... Did you tried the fiddle ?

Comment: I did. It doesn't set the mask if I type 0123456789

Comment: Yeah I get it, it seems there's weird behaviour with mask if you do it like this. I think you can open an issue on GutHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial solution**
@Toodoo is right, this is a bug already referenced on github.

One way to solve it, is to use `setCaretPosition`

In my case I added a ref in v-text and updated tel function

```
<v-text-field type="text" v-model="tel" :mask="mask" ref="tel></v-text-field>
```

and

```
 watch: {
        tel(v) {
            if (!v) {
                this.mask = ""
                return false
            }
            if (v.charAt(0) === "0") {
                this.tel = "+33"
                this.mask = "33 # ## ## ## ##"
                this.$refs.tel.setCaretPosition(3)
            }
        }
    }
```